# Script timing with FFMPEG and PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm running into a very strange bug.

Here's my command console output:

```
ffmpeg -i /transcodes/original/883_1000_1403436916_00001.MTS -y -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -

movflags faststart -crf 20 -profile:v high -level:v 4.0 -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 12000k -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 256k /transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_HQ.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -s 848x480 -tune zerolatency -movflags faststart -crf 25 -profile:v main -level:v 3.1 -maxrate 1400k -bufsize 1400k -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 256k /transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_SQ.mp4 -ss 166.16 -f image2 -vframes 1 /transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_poster.jpg -ss 166.16 -f image2 -vf scale=-1:240 -vframes 1 /transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_thumb.jpg

ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 13 2014 02:40:27 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/ubuntu/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '/transcodes/original/883_1000_1403436916_00001.MTS':
  Duration: 00:04:11.74, start: 0.382511, bitrate: 25222 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
[swscaler @ 0x216fe40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x2188c20] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] MB rate (489110) > level limit (245760)
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=2 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=1 slices=2 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=6000 vbv_bufsize=12000 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] using SAR=160/159
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] profile Main, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=2 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=1 slices=2 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=25.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1400 vbv_bufsize=1400 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_HQ.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.43.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, max. 6000 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 libfdk_aac
Output #1, mp4, to '/transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_SQ.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.43.100
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 848x480 [SAR 160:159 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, max. 1400 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 libx264
    Stream #1:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 libfdk_aac
Output #2, image2, to '/transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_poster.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.43.100
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 mjpeg
Output #3, image2, to '/transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_thumb.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.43.100
    Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 427x240 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #1:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
  Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (mjpeg))
  Stream #0:0 -> #3:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (mjpeg))
frame=15090 fps=1.0 q=39.0 q=30.0 q=6.6 q=4.3 size=  193843kB time=00:04:11.75 bitrate=6307.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=15088    
[mp4 @ 0x210ae00] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
[mp4 @ 0x210ae00] Unable to re-open /transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_HQ.mp4 output file for the second pass (faststart)
[mp4 @ 0x214fc20] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
[mp4 @ 0x214fc20] Unable to re-open /transcodes/883_1000_1403436916_00001_SQ.mp4 output file for the second pass (faststart)
frame=15090 fps=1.0 q=39.0 Lq=30.0 q=6.6 q=4.3 size=  193843kB time=00:04:11.77 bitrate=6307.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=15088    
video:212914kB audio:15741kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] frame I:162   Avg QP:23.31  size: 38205
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] frame P:14928 Avg QP:25.47  size: 12322
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] mb I  I16..4: 24.9% 70.4%  4.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] mb P  I16..4:  2.2%  3.2%  0.0%  P16..4: 38.3%  3.7%  4.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:48.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] 8x8 transform intra:60.6% inter:94.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 25.5% 50.7% 2.8% inter: 9.7% 17.3% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] i16 v,h,dc,p: 43% 17% 10% 29%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 13% 34%  4%  4%  4%  5%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 18% 13%  5%  7%  6%  7%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] i8c dc,h,v,p: 64% 15% 19%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.2% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] ref P L0: 67.7% 14.5% 13.8%  4.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2143e60] kb/s:6042.08
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] frame I:72    Avg QP:24.70  size: 14016
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] frame P:15018 Avg QP:28.46  size:  1783
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] mb I  I16..4: 39.4%  0.0% 60.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] mb P  I16..4:  0.8%  0.0%  0.3%  P16..4: 36.3%  4.1%  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:56.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 32.1% 41.1% 7.1% inter: 3.9% 6.6% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] i16 v,h,dc,p: 50% 12% 10% 27%
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 34% 15% 22%  5%  5%  5%  6%  5%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] i8c dc,h,v,p: 67% 11% 19%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.7% UV:0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] ref P L0: 65.0% 22.3% 10.0%  2.6%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2150680] kb/s:882.93
```

I've tried adding sleep(5) after:

```
        exec($cmd, $out, $ret);
```

to give the script time to move the moov atom to the front before uploading the local file to s3 and then deleting the local file, but it is not 100% reliable.

Any ideas?

Comment: not clear on what you are asking

Comment: It appears as soon as FFMPEG starts pass two (moving the moov atom to the front of the file), the execute function has returned and continues on with the rest of the script. I'm asking why is that so and how can I wait until I know the moov atom has been moved to the beginning before continuing with the rest of my script?

Comment: your php script wont continue until what ever exec runs finishes

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's not the case though. I uploaded 10 videos, 5 of them gave me that error "Unable to re-open output file for the second pass (faststart)", even if I sleep for 5 seconds before continuing to upload my encoded files. I'm pretty sure that I'm getting that error message because the input file I'm using is deleted at the end of my script, before ffmpeg has time to mov the moov atom to the front (which it says can take a while from their website)

Comment: odd, perhaps move the files out of system temp to your own temp and see if that works

Comment: I've set it up so both the input file and the output file are set explicitly. I used to read the input file directly from S3, but because of these weird corrupted files I download the uploaded file first, and then use it as input. For output same thing. I could try not deleting the source files right away, but I still have the problem where I want to upload the encoded files into the user's account as soon as fast as possible, but if the ffmpeg command hasn't really finished, I can'd do that yet.